# How to properly connect to BigQuery from FastAPI application running in CloudRun?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a FastAPI app running in CloudRun which needs to fetch data from BigQuery inside the same GCP project.
What I'm doing is something like this. I have bigquery.py module where I store my functions that do the fetching and processing of data. And I call them from route functions.

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery


client = bigquery.Client()


async def get_data(id: int) -> list[dict]:
    query = """
        SELECT * 
        FROM `my-proj.my-dataset.my-table`
        WHERE id = id
    """
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
        query_parameters=[
            bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("id", "INT64", id)
       ]
    )
    query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)

    results = []
    for row in query_job:
        results.append(dict(row.items()))
    return results
```

To be precise, where should I initiate the BigQuery client? Inside each function or in the outer scope and reuse it inside the functions?

Answer (score 0):

FastAPI has its own mechanism called [Depends](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) for exactly your use case.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should inject BigQuery client as a dependency in my route functions and pass it down to the functions that do the data fetching?

Comment: That's exactly what they're suggesting to do.